# Are there deadlock risks in ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

Here is one example of many: You can bind one ReactiveCocoa property to another: `property <~ otherProperty`. What if you also do `otherProperty <~ property`? Will this create a deadlock?

In general, what is the risk of deadlocks in ReactiveCocoa? Can you suggest some strategies to avoid them?